# Font with A without horizontal bar

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I'm trying to find the font used on this website for the name of the singer https://www.lindsayell.com/

[image: Lindasy Ell Logo]

I found this one which is similar https://www.dafont.com/adam.font?text=LINDSAY+ELL
But the S is not going that far in the start and ending segment.

Do you know a similar font that has an A without the horizontal bar and which is compatible with international languages including accents?

I want a font like that for my website and some other projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar to [Posterama Pro 2001 Thin](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/posterama/2001-thin/) via myfonts.com

[image]

The web logo is a custom design (*deleted horizontal A stroke*) made from [Avenir Next Pro Ultralight](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/avenir-next-pro/pro-ultralight/)

[image: Lindsay ell]

[image: Avenir]
[image: The Project]